# Default Website Default page iis 8

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-8

i want to set default page for mydomain.com

set default page default.aspx for defaultwebsite(mydomain.com)

1. i have hosted my web application on iis 8 defaultwebsite
2. i have added my webApplication in defaultwebsite(via Add Application
   option)
3. There is two applications in defaultwebsite
         a)mywebapplication
         b)mywebapi
4. i have set Binding for defaultwebsite is mydomain.com
5. folder structure  mywebapplication/views/default.aspx
6. changes in defaultwebsite  web.config file

getting internal server error

any help will be appreciated

Comment: IIS will look for default.aspx by default. You do not need to specify it. And the error "internal server error" is not related to the default page setting. Check the detailed error in the server logs and see what the problem is.